# verification testbench ports need directions or not necessary?

Tags: system-verilog

I am having a question regarding declaring signals in verification testbench/interface. As i am told in the textbook, i suppose to declare each signal with directions in my testbench or interface, but strangely i can still get correct results without doing that. I can just declare all signals as "logic", and feed them to the correct input/output ports of my DUT.

So I am confused if input/output declaration is necessary for a verification testbench? verification testbenches are not necessarily to be synthesizable, aren't them?  even some examples in my book didn't write the testbench with input/output ports. Sometimes i see plainly "module test();" all signals in the module are declared as "logic".

can someone give some detailed explanations on this? Do I must declare directions for my signals in my testbench?

Comment: `logic` is a datatype in verilog, it does not indicate the port direction. You can have `logic input` or `logic output` to specify the port direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top-level modules in a testbench have no ports, and therefore no directions to specify. A lower level module needs ports if you want to pass signals across the module boundary up to the higher level module and a port declaration requires a direction. Simulators do not care whether a module description is being used for a testbench or the design and might ignore the specified direction. Synthesis tools require correct signal directions.

SystemVerilog's `interface` construct is slightly more complicated because it is a collection of signals, each with the potential to be used as a port. A `modport` construct used within an `interface` specifies the signals that be used as ports and their directions. As with module ports, modports require directions as part of the port syntax.

Comment: i know that modports need directions. But modport is not necessarily part of interface. What I am asking is that i often see interface without declaring signal directions, but the interface can still be passed to the testbench without causing any problem. The testbench seems to catch anything disregard of its direction. For example, test(interface if); what is inside interface doesn't necessarily to have directions, and i still get the signal values. Should I always,must, specify directions for signals in the interfaces just for the testbench?

Comment: You are correct that a `modport` is not necessary for the operation of a testbench. Think of it as just a layer of safety that you can choose to use.